# Getting hundredth integer from a tuple (python)

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to get the hundredth integers from a tuple. The question goes:

> Implement a function `get_hundredth(a, b, c)`
>   that takes in 3 positive integers as arguments and returns a tuple of digits at the respective hundredth position.
>
> If a given integer is less than 100, its hundredth position can be viewed as 0. If the input is invalid, return `None` for that integer.
>
> `get_hundredth(1234, 509, 80633)` should return `(2, 5, 6)`
>   and `get_hundredth(4024, 81, 2713)` should return `(0, 0, 7)`

This is what I have so far:

```
def get_hundredth(a, b, c):

    a, b, c = str(a), str(b), str(c)

    return int(a[-3:-2]), int(b[-3:-2]), int(c[-3:-2])
```

how do I make it to 0 if it's under 100?

Comment: I think you're confusing "hundredth"  with "hundreds"

Comment: If a is "boo", you will return "b". Is that really ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the other answers, don't address the problem of when to return `None`...

```
def get_hundredth(a,b,c):
    def hundreds(x):
        try:
            return (x // 100) % 10 if (isinstance(x, int) and x > 0) else None
        except TypeError:
            return None
    return tuple(map(hundreds, (a,b,c)))

print(get_hundredth(1234, 509, 80633)) # (2, 5, 6)
print(get_hundredth(-89, 81.85, 'test')) # (None, None, None)
```

Comment: @Alexander, though an "invalid" input could also be a negative number. I have made the proper edits

Comment: Missed it, thanks (though it seems to imply error in the integer maybe negative). So what about all other numeric types that aren't integers? Are they valid or invalid (you are assuming valid).

Comment: Fine, for me (and given the acceptance for the OP too). It still accepts floats without error.

Comment: @AChampion I'm a completion-ist, so I think that is the final edit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the hundreds then use `mod` (`%`) operator, e.g.:

```
h = x // 100 % 10
```

So for your function would look like (updated for error handling):

```
def get_hundredth(a, b, c):
    return tuple(x//100 % 10 if isinstance(x, int) and x > 0 else None for x in (a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would return the desired value for one integer:

```
def _get_hundreds(a):
    return (a % 1000) / 100
```

discard everything but last 3 digits (`% 1000`), then get the hudreds (`/ 100`).
For 3 integers:

```
def get_hundreds(a, b, c):
    return map(_get_hundreds, (a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 solution:

```
def get_hundredth(a, b, c):
    return [i / 100 % 10 for i in [a, b, c]]

>>> get_hundredth(1234, 509, 80633)
[2, 5, 6]

>>> get_hundredth(4024, 81, 2713)
[0, 0, 7]
```

Comment: What if any of them is invalid, eg. not divisible by 100?

Comment: The last example returns 0 when the value is 81.  What value did you have in mind?

Comment: This assumes integer division (should really use `//` to force it and be correct in python3), x // 100 equals 0 if i < 100 and just drops any fractional part if > 100. Should really return a `tuple`.

Comment: @Alexander eg. when a = "boo". Ah. The question was edited.

Comment: It will throw an exception `TypeError`

Comment: @hruske You get what you'd expect: an error.  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @AChampion This answer is prefaced with "Python 2 solution" (there wasn't a Python 3 tag).  But yes, I agree it would be best to use `//`.

Comment: Error is a good thing in general, but it isn't according to (admittedly a bit silly) spec.

Comment: Understood, `//` works for both and would also do something sensible with floats (though outside of the OP's question).

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_hundredth(*k):
    return map(lambda x: x / 100 % 10, k)
```

This doesn't do error correction, but it'll get you closer to your solution. Since you're doing the same operation on all arguments, you can get them as a list (`k`) and then apply `map` to all of the arguments.